# netty-incubator-codec-quic: How to get remoteAddress?

Tags: java, netty, quic

I need to know the remote address at the server side. I tried bellow ways and failed:

1. `QuicStreamChannel.remoteAddress()` returns `QuicStreamAddress`, which cannot be casted to `InetSocketAddress`. `QuicStreamAddress` or `QuicConnectionAddress` does not contain remote IP address or port at all.
2. class `io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf` cannot be cast to class `io.netty.channel.socket.DatagramPacket` so I cannot use `DatagramPacket.sender()` to get the sender address.
3. `(QuicChannel) (ctx.channel().parent())).sslEngine().getPeerHost()` -- this returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to intercept `QuicConnectionEvent`s. These events contain the address. Be aware that the address can change (in this case a new event is fired).

```
new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
        if (evt instanceof QuicConnectionEvent) {
            QuicConnectionEvent event = (QuicConnectionEvent) evt;
            System.out.println(event.newAddress());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I just moved from `netty-incubator-codec-native-quic` 0.0.35.Final to 0.0.53.Final, Netbeans complains cannot find symbol `io.netty.incubator.codec.quic.QuicConnectionEvent`.